# Change button text using D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3, I am trying various stuff to explore the library. I have the following `button` and I want to change its text:

```
<button id="showhide" onclick="myFunction()">Show me the graph</button>
```

I tried various stuff like:

```
d3.select("showhide").html("asdsa");

d3.select("showhide").innerHTML("asdsa");

d3.select("showhide").text("asdsa");
```

but none of them works. I know how to do it using DOM or jQuery, I am wondering how to do it using D3js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are trying to select the `button` using its ID, you need to prepend `'#'` to your selector:

```
d3.select("#showhide").text("asdsa");
```

If you'd rather, you can use D3 to add an event listener to the `button`, e.g.

```
d3.select("#showhide").on("click", function(){
    d3.select(this).text("asdsa");
});
```

See a JSfiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/LPM53/).